# Force refresh of Upstream TabViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload, nstabviewcontroller

I am developing an app wherein a user action should lead to the reduction of `TabController` options (icons) from 5 down to 3.
I understand the code required to modify the `TabController` but am unable to force it to refresh (`viewDidLoad`) since the `ViewController` where the user interacts is several steps downstream from the tab controller (the flow aslo includes a `NavController`).  As a result

> self.tabBarController?.viewDidLoad()

does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
    print("pressed tab refresh")
    print(self.tabBarController)
    //this next line confirms that I can "see" the tab controller in question
    print(self.tabBarController?.title)

    //expect this to work
    self.tabBarController?.viewDidLoad()

    //trying this as well
    var setTBC = self.tabBarController
    setTBC?.delegate = self
    setTBC?.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: did u create tabbar using storyboard or through code , you need to use delegate for it , this direct method won't work , but its very good question

Comment: `viewDidLoad` isn't something that you are supposed to call.  It's there for you to set up UI elements when the UIKit calls you.

Comment: Thanks Shobhakar. I created the tab bar via storyboard.  I've also tried forcing that upstream tab bar into a variable and making it it's own delegate but this produced an error.  I'll update above with my code

Comment: Thanks Phillip, I wasn't aware.  Is there a better way to force a container view controller or tab controller to update while allowing the user to remain in their current ('child') controller?